# Docker in Proxmox

Tags: docker, lxc

I've setup a home server with Proxmox v4 and want to run a Docker container. How should I go about this? Should I just setup Docker inside an LXC container or should I create a full VM and use one of the minimal OS's like Atomic Host / CoreOS / RancherOS?

As is probably obvious from the phrasing of this question, I'm new to both containers and Proxmox so please keep that in mind when responding. This home project is one thing I'm doing to rectify this. I am, however, not new to Linux or virtualization. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm thinking about doing the same thing. [This post](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/running-docker-inside-lxc.24858/) worries me a little about going ahead and doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read a little bit before giving you my answer because I had a similar question.

The advantage of turning your docker into a CT (container) with LXC, as you probably know, will be performance and direct access to the proxmox storage.

The advantage of turning your docker into a VM with KVM, will be more secure for your proxmox (host), but you will loose 5-8% of performance.

If you will have only docker on your proxmox turn it as LXC
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/docker-support-in-proxmox.27474/

Usually : i'm using KVM for critical VM such as ERP or CRM and Container for others.

If it could help you, you could turn your question as : should/could I use a VPS (VirtualPrivateServer) or a Dedicated Server.
If the answer is a VPS, turn your docker into LXC.